# Facebook API: user allows permissions, then shares a pre-existing photo to their wall

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've been looking around trying to find a solution to my problem but no luck.

I would like to mimic the "feed" dialog which allows the user the ability to share a link on their wall.

However, I would like the user to share a pre-existing photo on their wall at full size.

If someone could help me out, that would be awesome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using the object_attachment param. I'm not certain it'll come out full size though. It'll look like a link story, but the image will pop open the photo viewer lightbox.

Here's a blog post announcing it:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/